# An iPhone purchased in the US: will it work in New Zealand?

Tags: usa, cellphones, new-zealand, phone-networks

I'm from New Zealand but am currently in the United States for the next few months. I plan to buy an unlocked iPhone 7 from Apple, use an AT&T SIM (which I already have) in it while I'm here, and then take it back to New Zealand.

I know the phone should be unlocked so I'm not too worried about that, but I don't really know much about the 3G and 4G bands. Are the iPhone 7 bands compatible with cellphone networks in New Zealand? I've tried searching already for an answer but most are from several years ago.

Answer (score 7):

It will work fine, you can check for any phone and network at sites like [Willmyphonework.net](https://willmyphonework.net/), where both US models of the iPhone 7 come up clear for all NZ phone networks on all frequencies (2G, 3G, 4G).

On a side note, you are required to pay import taxes on the phone when you take it home to New Zealand. The value of the phone (even a few months after purchase) exceeds the [NZ$700 personal goods concession](http://www.customs.govt.nz/features/charges/dutyfree/Pages/default.aspx). If you still go through the green channel or otherwise don't pay, you are comitting a criminal act. In practice, it is unlikely you would be caught, but if you were, penalties would likely be severe.

Comment: That website is super handy, thanks so much!
Also I had no idea about that so thank you for letting me know!